# C++, переопределение метода со сменой уровня доступа

Tags: c++, классы, override

Скажите, позволяет ли `C++` переопределить метод предка с изменением уровня доступа к этому методу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему бы нет, если вы про типа такого:

```
class B {
protected:
    virtual void print() const { std::cout << foo(); }      
public:
    virtual int foo() const { return 1; }
};
class H : public B {
protected:
    int foo() const final { return -1; }
public:
    void print() const override { std::cout << foo(); }    
};
```

Но только учитывайте, что при обращении к обьекту дочерного класса через  указатель(ссыльку) базового, получится:

```
 B* b = new H;
//b->print(); ошибка
cout << b->foo(); //правильно
```

Базовый класс скрывает свой метод, позволяя переопределять в производных классах. Не зависимо от того, что вы сделали его публичным в производном классе, указатель на виртуальную таблицу не найдет этот метод.

Answer (score 3):

Позволяет. Переопределять метод предка в потомке можно с любым уровнем доступа.

Разумеется это никак не влияет на тот факт, что контроль уровня доступа в С++ осуществляется на уровне статических типов и имен методов.

Comment: Интересно. Для полей ведь нельзя? А почему для методов можно? Или это только для виртуальных? А может и для полей тоже можно?

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Речь пока шла о *переопределении*. Что применимо только к виртуальным методам. Как сюда приплести поля - я не вижу.